# Erro trocar senha no sistema de login com PHP SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, null, senhas

Boa tarde, estou com um grande problema no qual não consigo troca a senha no sistema. O que está me ferrando é que parece que que o sqlsrv_fetch_array funciona de um modo diferente do mysql_fetch_array, tenho um código igual a esse usando MySQL e funciona de boa porém no SQL Server não está, então vim aqui pedindo ajuda nesse sistema.

```
public function alterarsenha($Nome, $Senha, $Novasenha, $Confirnovasenha){
        $sql = "SELECT SENHA FROM CADPES WHERE NOME = '$Nome'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  

        $senhabanco = '';
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $senhabanco = $row['SENHA'];
        }            
            if(($Senhanova == "") OR ($Confirsenha) == "" ){
                echo "Insira a nova senha!";
                //header('location:index.php');
            }else{
                if($Senha != $senhabanco){
                    echo "Nome ou senha inválido!";
                }else{
                   if($Novasenha != $Confirnovasenha){
                    echo "Campos da nova senha não conferem!";
                }else{
                    $upd = "UPDATE CADPES SET SENHA = '$Novasenha' WHERE NOME = '$NOME'";
                    $upd_query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql);

                        if($upd_query){
                            echo "Senha alterado com sucesso";
                            //header('location:index.php');
                        }else{
                            echo "Ocorreu um erro na trocra de Números";
                            //header('location:index.php');
                        }
                }
            }   
    }
```

estou preso aqui !

```
if($Senha != $senhabanco){
      echo "Nome ou senha inválido!";
}else{
```

Não sai dessa condição o problema é que a variável $senhabanco sempre está com o valor NULL mesmo eu tendo feito o while. E ja até tentei mudar a chave de lugar colocar no final mas resulta em outro erro.

Comment: Tentou imprimir os valores das duas variáveis com `var_dump()/print_r()`?

Comment: sim, dentro do while não imprimi nada, fora dele imprime null!

Answer (score 0):

Depois de fuçar por horas encontrei os 3 erros que fazia com que o sistema não rodasse.

1º no while, 2º query tinha passado o parâmetro errado e por ultimo no sqlsrv_query eu tinha colocado antes $sql.

```
public function alterarsenha($Nome, $Senha, $Novasenha, $Confirnovasenha){
        $sql = "SELECT SENHA FROM CADPES WHERE NOME = '$Nome'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  

    $senhabanco = '';
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){

        $senhabanco = $row['SENHA'];
    }            
        if(($Senhanova == "") OR ($Confirsenha) == "" ){
            echo "Insira a nova senha!";
            //header('location:index.php');
        }else{
            if($Senha != $senhabanco){
                echo "Nome ou senha inválido!";
            }else{
               if($Novasenha != $Confirnovasenha){
                echo "Campos da nova senha não conferem!";
            }else{
                $upd = "UPDATE CADPES SET SENHA = '$Novasenha' WHERE NOME = '$Nome'";
                $upd_query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $upd);

                    if($upd_query){
                        echo "Senha alterado com sucesso";
                        //header('location:index.php');
                    }else{
                        echo "Ocorreu um erro na trocra de Números";
                        //header('location:index.php');
                    }
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: Depois de fuçar por horas encontrei os 3 erros que fazia com que o sistema não rodasse. 1º no while, 2º query tinha passado o parâmetro errado e por ultimo no sqlsrv_query eu tinha colocado antes $sql.